# DOMPDF Image not found with site url

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, dompdf

Yes I have looked through all the other questions regarding this.
the typical relative path or turn remote resource true did not work.

What did work for me is when I upload the file into **any other websites** and link them from there all worked!

the problem is there is a wordpress cms with actual image in this pdf creation.

have tried server url, /path, ../path, http://example.com/path.

all returned something along the line of no image or image not found.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site2.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} AttorneyID=3 [NC]
rewriterule ^attorneys/attorney_detail.php http://www.site2.com/attorney/name/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's too bad, but what do you expect us to be able to help with? YOu've provided no code, no error messages, no examples. just some vague symptoms and some ranting.

Comment: the dompdf preview page everything displays fine, but when it gets output into pdf all you see is a grey box and the message `image not found` .. There aren't any error. but for example when i switch the img src to stack overflow logo image. it displays fine.

Comment: If all other sites work, I'm wondering if you have a redirection in your site's .htaccess.  I'm not sure how PHP/DOMPDF would handle that.  So if you linked to http://example.com, but your .htaccess redirects all http://example.com calls to http://www.example.com, it might cause problems.  Putting it another way - are you using the canonical URL for your image?

Comment: updated with my redriects, not sure if that will cause issues, theres also supercache plugin redirects but that shouldn't be image related, and no CDN setup.

Comment: Not sure either, just a thought.  So what's the URL you're using for the image?  If it's of the form `http://www.site2.com/<something>`, you can ignore my question.  But if it's of the form `http://site1.com/<something>`, you might be better off using `http://www.site2.com/<something>`.  Or (checking another way) - open Chrome dev tools, network tab, check "preserve log", and navigate to the image URL.  If you see redirections, try the final version of the URL (the last request).

Comment: Still an issue? Might help to see a sample of the HTML and some additional info on how the image is referenced (e.g. the reference goes directly to the image vs the to a PHP script which does some image processing).

Comment: This wasn't resolved but right now I link resources to a rackspace test domain (which is the same resource file) and the pdf creator have no issue displaying the image. http://www.certilmanbalin.com/attorney/jennifer-ng/pdf-preview/ example